# Python JSON format API dictionary help. 'Expected expression Pylance' error

Tags: python, json, dictionary, discord.py, openweathermap

I am trying to understand how to parse and only return specific data on the JSON dictionary of a weather API. I have two files, the main file has the JSON request `data = json.loads(request.get(url).content)` and the main function that my API is running on. The second file is file with all my functions, including `parse_data` which I am trying to solve.

This is the return of data from the JSON dict:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 10.99,
    "lat": 44.34
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 501,
      "main": "Rain",
      "description": "moderate rain",
      "icon": "10d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 298.48,
    "feels_like": 298.74,
    "temp_min": 297.56,
    "temp_max": 300.05,
    "pressure": 1015,
    "humidity": 64,
    "sea_level": 1015,
    "grnd_level": 933
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 0.62,
    "deg": 349,
    "gust": 1.18
  },
  "rain": {
    "1h": 3.16
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 100
  },
  "dt": 1661870592,
  "sys": {
    "type": 2,
    "id": 2075663,
    "country": "IT",
    "sunrise": 1661834187,
    "sunset": 1661882248
  },
  "timezone": 7200,
  "id": 3163858,
  "name": "Zocca",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Now this a snippet on my second file including parse data:

```
key_features = {
    'temp' : 'Temperature',
    'feels_like' : 'Feels Like',
    'temp_min' : 'Minimum Temperature',
    'temp_max' : 'Maximum Temperature'
}

def parse_data(data):
    data = data['main'], data['weather']
    print(data)
    return data

def weather_message(data, location):
    location = location.title()
    message = discord.Embed(
        title=f'{location} Weather (Celsius)',
        description=f'Here is the weather in {location}.',
        color=color
    )
    
    for key in key_features:
        message.add_field(
            name=key_features[key],
            value=str(data[key]),
            inline=False
        )
    return message
```

What I'm trying to do is to only return the values of those in my `key_features`. For example in the `parse_data` function have tried `data = del data['main']['humidity']` and it has an error 'Expected expression Pylance'. I would appreciate any help on solving my problem it's my first time working with APIs and reading documentation and I'm very overwhelmed.

Comment: `del` is not a traditional function - it doesn't return anything. `del foo[bar]` just deletes the `bar` element from the collection `foo`, it doesn't return the newly modified `foo`.

Comment: @MattDMo `del` **is not a function**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga correct, that's what I said.

Comment: Hello thanks for the help, I was looking through FreeCodeCamp.org it said that to delete items through a dictionary I should use the `del` keyword. They also say I can use pop and popitem methods but I'm still trying to figure it all out. popitem would only delete the last instance of the list but how do I delete `humidity` for example?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get only the data you specified in the `key_features` dictionary.

You can do for example:

```py
data = {
    "coord": {"lon": 10.99, "lat": 44.34},
    "weather": [
        {"id": 501, "main": "Rain", "description": "moderate rain", "icon": "10d"}
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 298.48,
        "feels_like": 298.74,
        "temp_min": 297.56,
        "temp_max": 300.05,
        "pressure": 1015,
        "humidity": 64,
        "sea_level": 1015,
        "grnd_level": 933,
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {"speed": 0.62, "deg": 349, "gust": 1.18},
    "rain": {"1h": 3.16},
    "clouds": {"all": 100},
    "dt": 1661870592,
    "sys": {
        "type": 2,
        "id": 2075663,
        "country": "IT",
        "sunrise": 1661834187,
        "sunset": 1661882248,
    },
    "timezone": 7200,
    "id": 3163858,
    "name": "Zocca",
    "cod": 200,
}

key_features = {
    "temp": "Temperature",
    "feels_like": "Feels Like",
    "temp_min": "Minimum Temperature",
    "temp_max": "Maximum Temperature",
}


def parse_data(data, key_features):
    out = {}
    for k, v in key_features.items():
        out[v] = data["main"][k]
    return out


new_data = parse_data(data, key_features)

for k, v in new_data.items():
    print(f"{k:<30} {v:<30}")
```

Prints:

```py
Temperature                    298.48                        
Feels Like                     298.74                        
Minimum Temperature            297.56                        
Maximum Temperature            300.05
```

Comment: ...nice bit of code !

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply! You are correct I wanted to do something like this but I wanted it so it returns only main with the key features value on the list. My weather_message is supposed to print it out on the discord app and i'm having trouble making it to do so, i'm positive it's something to do my parse_data though. I have an idea of what to do from looking at your code thank you!